Open WSL by Default in a command-line shell
Unfortunately the insoluble problem of jerky scrolling, un-smooth scrolling has left me with no choice but to ditch Ubuntu and go back to Windows. However, I've absolutely fallen in love with the Linux shell and so have installed WSL.
Now, is there a way to have WSL open by default in Powershell/Command Prompt? I'd like to open wsl either by some app and be able to go straight into a Linux session. Is there a way to do this?

You can install Microsoft Terminal from the Windows store which will let you open terminal tabs with shells directly to WSL distros.

To Open WSL from CommandLine: wsl -d Ubuntu. Replace Ubuntu with the name of your installed distribution if it's different. To check wsl --status
To make it as default, you can add the code to $Profile of PowerShell.
This will create it automatically. edited needed:
$DocPath = "$Home\Documents\WindowsPowerShell"
if ( $Host.Version.Major -eq 7) {$DocPath = "$Home\Documents\PowerShell"}
if ( !(Test-Path $DocPath) ) {md $DocPath}
'wsl -d Ubuntu; CLS' > $profile


As @squillman has pointed there's Windows Terminal , which is a host application for the command-line shells.
If you decide to use Terminal you can edit the settings.json to have the default profile be your wsl.
In settings.json you'll find the GUID for wsl. This GUID will be the value to place in the defaultProfile field.
Note: Terminal automatically creates WSL profiles upon the creation of a WSL distro.

I did something similar using Windows terminal, but just used the settings option in the application to set Ubuntu as my default
